# How to display the system install date?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, installation

I have systems here that are using Windows XP SP3 and I am wondering if there is a way to see how old they are. Meaning **to find the date that Windows was installed** on the computer.

Is it possible, do you know where to locate this information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Start > Run > cmd.exe > systeminfo
```

It will analyze your system and you can see the "original install date" in the generated list.